# Importing subfolders in a typescript npm package

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I'm creating a package for `npm` but I want it to be imported in the following way:

```js
import myPackage from 'my-package';
import { subFunction1, subFunction2 } from 'my-package/subfunctions';
```

When trying to use the package I created, it loads properly the root file but produces the following error for the subfolder:

> Cannot find module 'my-package/subfunctions'

My current folder structure that is being published to npm is:

```
index.js
index.d.ts
subfunctions/
  sub-function-1.js
  sub-function-1.d.ts
  sub-function-2.js
  sub-function-2.d.ts
  index.js
  index.d.ts
```

And my types declaration on the `package.json` file is the following:

```
"types": [
  "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "./dist/subfunctions/index.d.ts",
],
```

Below I show the content of the files `index.d.ts` (1) and `subfunctions/index.d.ts` (2):

**(1)**

```
import myCode from './lib/my-code';
export default myCode;
```

**(2)**

```
export { subFunction1 } from './sub-function-1';
export { subFunction2 } from './sub-function-2';
```

How can I import from this subfolder?

Comment: Looking at other package.json files, they normally create a sub folder, say called lib.  And then have a `"main": "dist/index.js"`  So if you moved your code into a directory lib, and altered the package.json file, does this work.

Comment: @Keith I don't get it. My current package.json has `"main": "dist/index.js"` on it.

Comment: I have exact problem. @GabrielSiedler did you found any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but thought I'd share this answer. It looks like there's a newer field in `package.json`, `"exports"` (supported since Node.js 12+, ~2019), which is offered [as an alternative to `"main"`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_exports) and may be exactly what you (and anyone else with this same issue) are looking for.

While I haven't tested this myself, `"exports"` supports ["subpath exports"](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-exports) which allow you to export submodule code from a different path than your main:

```json
{
  "main": "./index.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./index.js",
    "./subFunctions": "./src/subFunctions/index.js"
  }
}
```

On the importing end, this would result in exactly what you're looking for:

```js
import myPackage from "my-package";
import subFunctions from "my-package/subFunctions";
```

Or presumably (this is the part the docs aren't clear on, so I'm not 100% sure, but it stands to reason):

```js
import myPackage from "my-package";
import { subFunction1, subFunction2 } from "my-package/subFunctions";
```

...assuming that `src/subFunctions/index.js` has matching named exports.

Apologies if any of this is misleading as I'm just getting this from the docs (which I stumbled upon randomly a few days after just as randomly stumbling upon this question), but if it works, hope this helps someone.