# How can I import from a subfolder in a Typescript package?

Tags: javascript, typescript, monorepo

I have a shared library in a Typescript monorepo that I need to access from `foo/` and `bar/` packages:

```
root/
  packages/
     foo/
     bar/
     shared/
       dist/
         index.js
         index.d.ts
         index.d.ts.map
           some/
             nested/
               thing/
                 index.js
                 index.d.ts
                 index.d.ts.map
```

**packages/shared/package.json**:

```
...
"main": "dist/index.js",
"typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
"scripts": {
   "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json"
}
...
```

**packages/shared/dist/index.js**:

```
export { default as TopLevelThing } from './some/other/folder'
```

**packages/shared/dist/some/nested/thing/index.js**:

```
export { default as NestedThing } from './NestedThing'
```

Now, from files in `foo/` or `bar/`, I can do this:

```
import { TopLevelThing } from '@app/shared'
import { NestedThing } from '@app/shared/dist/some/nested/thing'
```

But the `dist/` part is clearly not something I want in the namespace. I want to be able to import like this:

```
import { TopLevelThing } from '@app/shared'
import { NestedThing } from '@app/shared/some/nested/thing'
```

How can I achieve that?

Related to and possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50936942/importing-subfolders-in-a-typescript-npm-package), but not requiring npm publication.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_package_entry_points) field in `package.json` in Node.js v12 and later. This allows you link e.g. `/some/nested` to actually use the script at `/dist/some/nested` instead of the default "check the filesystem" mechanic.

Comment: This looks promising, but I can't quite seem to make it work. `"exports": { "./whatever": "./dist/some/nested/thing/index.js" }` / `import { NestedThing } from @app/shared/whatever` gives me a `ModuleNotFound` error. What am I missing here?

Comment: How did you resolve it? I have the same problem.

Comment: I had the same problem, changing `"moduleResolution"` to `"nodenext"` as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/74485520/1493269 fixed it for me.